# several idle connections SET bytea_output

Tags: postgresql

i have a situation that i don't know if it is normal, i think not.

I have several idle connections with the query `SET bytea_output='escape'`, so i arrive to max_connections and have issues with my applications, why are there so many connections idle with that query?

Answer (score 2):

Many libraries which manage connections for you will execute some housekeeping queries on the new connection before returning it to the caller.  `SET bytea_output='escape'` is just the type of housekeeping query you might expect to see.

So the likely explanation is that someone keeps asking for a new connections, and then immediately forgets about it without either using it or closing it.  To figure out who, you should be looking at other fields of "pg_stat_activity", like usename, application_name, and client_addr.

And ultimately if you don't know who is connecting to your database, you should be changing the passwords or other authentication methods.